# Using JS,JSON,PHP, and MYSQL to populate a form SELECT options

Tags: javascript

I cannot figure out what is wrong with this script:

```
var url="json.php";
$.getJSON(url,function(data){
$.each(data.members, function(i,user){
     selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option(user.title,user.aid);
     });
     });
```

The goal is to run json.php to get data from my MYSQL and take that data to create a SELECT in a form.
I had thought the above code would create something like this:

```
selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('Private','13');
selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('Public','14');
selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('Friends','15');
```

The PHP script json.php works. It gathers the data from the MYSQL and displays it as I want when I use this JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var url="json.php";
$("#userdata tbody").html("");
$.getJSON(url,function(data){
$.each(data.members, function(i,user){
var tblRow =
"<tr>"
+"<td>"+user.aid+"</td>"
+"<td>"+user.title+"</td>"
+"</tr>" ;
$(tblRow).appendTo("#userdata tbody");
});
});
});
```

So far I get nothing populated in the SELECT dropdown
This is the entire JS script thus far. It is not my script and I know very little about how it actually works prior to me wanting the dynamic dropdown.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function setOptions(chosen){
var selbox = document.formName.table;
selbox.options.length = 0;
if (chosen == " ") {
    selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('No database selected',' ');
    }
if (chosen == "1") {
    var url="json.php";
    $.getJSON(url,function(data){
    $.each(data.members, function(i,user){
            selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option(user.title,user.aid);

    });
    });
    }
if (chosen == "2") {
    selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('second choice - option one','twoone');
    selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('second choice - option two','twotwo');
    selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('second choice - option three','twothree');
    selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('second choice - option four','twofour');
    }
if (chosen == "3") {
    selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('third choice - option one','threeone');
    selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('third choice - option two','threetwo');
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a debugging service. Include what you have tried yourself to make this easier to answer and more relevant to future visitors.

Comment: What I have tried is all above, and now includes @HashTeck's suggestion. The third code shown works to display the data in a table. I want it to create a dropdown menu instead. I just need to know how to dynamically create the dropdown options for the data from the json so that the area just passed chosen=="1" looks the same as just passed chosen=="2" but after newOption has MY data and not static variables

Comment: I guess you need to learn how to debug yourself.

Comment: I do not see it as a bug since the script works as a table. How do I change new Option('second choice - option one','twoone') to new Option(user.title,user.aid) properly is all I think I need

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Had you placed the json.php code that would have been better. Anyways, make sure that your PHP script returns the JSON encoded code that is understandable to jQuery.

You can check below option to achieve the same too as I doubt on your specially on this line

```
selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option(user.title,user.aid);
```

Here is my sugestion

```
$.getJSON("json.php", function(j)
{
    var options = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++)
    {
        options += '<option value="' + j[i].optionValue + '">' + j[i].optionDisplay + '</option>';
    }
    $("#select_box").html(options);  // put your select box ID here
});
```

Comment: Sorry. I'm not good with JS. When I use your suggestion, FireBug gives me this error: ReferenceError: $ is not defined
 

$.getJSON("json.php", function(j)

Comment: You need to attach jQuery. In your code you used jQuery, how did you use it without attaching jquery file ? 

Anyways, download jQuery from this link OR google jQuery CDN. 

http://code.jquery.com/

BTW: Bugs are good, they teach us programming. 

Also, I don't think there was any problem in my post that it was given negative marking.